# Dax Pivot Table Sum Independent of Slicer

Tags: pivot-table, dax, powerpivot

I am using PowerPivot in Excel. 
I am selling products at 2 separate locations, I have a column that differentiates and is populated with the store location. I have a slicer option that separates the  view based in the store location and of course the option to select both location to see the combined sales. I also have the calculated in stock for each location.

I want to bring in the amount I have in the warehouse (that serves for both lo cations) for reference at the end (right side) of the pivot table. I have that in a separate table with the unique item numbers. I can build a query from the data source (Access) to bring in the warehouse stock qty twice (labeled the location near it) but that would work only when viewing each location separately but not when combined - it will show me double.
I need a number in the sum that will always be the same no matter the slicer option.

Comment: [DAX Filter Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/filter-functions-dax) like `ALL allow you to adjust your evaluation context. Do you have measures or are you using implicit measures by dragging and dropping columns?

Comment: Dragging and dropping columns

Comment: You'll likely need to write proper measures to do this.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Thank you - will just have to brush up on the basic skills